# Código de anunciante não funciona

Tags: php

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema de anunciante via link e quando um usuário clicasse no link iria abrir uma nova janela e contar como uma visita e descontar do saldo do anunciante, mas não ta funcionando e não sei o que está dando errado:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
require_once '../global.php';
require_once ROOT_PATH . '/inc/analyzer.class.php';

function kill() { System::redirect(SITE_LOCATION); exit; };
if (isset($_GET['uid']) && isset($_GET['url'])) {
    $G_UID = intval($_GET['uid']);

    $G_URL_R = $G_UID . '/' . ($_GET['adt'] != 1 ? 'banner/' : '');
    $G_URL = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $G_URL = substr($G_URL, strpos($G_URL, $G_URL_R) + strlen($G_URL_R));

    $G_ADT = $_GET['adt'] != 1 ? 'Top Banner' : 'Interstitial';
    $urlsb = substr($G_URL, 0, strpos($G_URL, '://'));
    if (!$urlsb) {
        $G_URL = 'http://' . $G_URL;
    }
    if (!is_numeric($G_UID) || !Utilities::validateURL($G_URL)) {
        kill();
    }
} else if(!preg_match('|^[0-9a-zA-Z]{1,6}$|', $_GET['to'])) {
    kill();
}

$G_SHORT = false;
if ($G_UID && $G_URL && $G_ADT) {
    $surl  = SITE_LOCATION;
    $db    = System::getDB();
    $user  = $G_UID;
    if ($tmp = $db->getField($_GLOBAL['TABLES']['LINKS'], 'short_url', 
                             "`long_url`='{$G_URL}' AND `adtype`='{$G_ADT}' AND `user`='{$user}'")) {
        $short = $tmp;
        $data  = System::getDB()->getRows($_GLOBAL['TABLES']['LINKS'], "`short_url`='{$short}'", '', '1');
    } else {
        $data = array('long_url' => $G_URL, 'adtype' => $G_ADT, 'user' => $user);
        $db->query('LOCK TABLES ' . $_GLOBAL['TABLES']['LINKS'] . ' WRITE;');
        $lid = $db->insert($_GLOBAL['TABLES']['LINKS'], $data);
        $db->query('UNLOCK TABLES');
        $short = $surl . Utilities::compressInt($lid);
        $db->update($_GLOBAL['TABLES']['LINKS'], array('short_url' => $short), "`id`='{$lid}'");
        $data  = System::getDB()->getRows($_GLOBAL['TABLES']['LINKS'], "`id`='{$lid}'", '', '1');
    }
    $G_SHORT = $short;
} else {
    $surl  = Utilities::removeURLQueries(Utilities::getCurrentURL());
    $data  = System::getDB()->getRows($_GLOBAL['TABLES']['LINKS'], "`short_url`='{$surl}'", '', '1');
}

$lid   = $data['id'];
$oid   = $data['user'];
$url   = $data['long_url'];
$title = $data['title'];
$adtyp = $data['adtype'] == 'Interstitial' ? 1 : 2;
if (!$url) kill();

if ($data['adtype'] == 'None') {
    $analyzer = new Analyzer($lid, $oid, 0);
    $analyzer->_record($adtype);
    System::redirect($url);
}

function get_ad() {
    global $_GLOBAL, $data;
    $a  = new Analyzer(0, 0, 0);
    if ($a->_isCrawler()) die('Crawlers are not allowed here');
    $db =  System::getDB();
    $t  = $data['adtype'] != 'Interstitial' ? 'Banner' : 'Interstitial';
    $cc = $a->country($a->ip());
    $ci = $db->getField($_GLOBAL['TABLES']['PACKAGES'], 'id', "`code`='{$cc}' AND `advert_type`='{$t}'");
    $c  = $db->getRows($_GLOBAL['TABLES']['CAMPAIGNS'], "`status`='2' AND `advert_type`='{$t}'");
    $valid = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($c); $i++) {
        if ($c[$i]['spent_today'] >= $c[$i]['daily_budget'] && $c[$i]['daily_budget'] != 0) continue;
        $pkg = explode(';', $c[$i]['packages']);
        foreach ($pkg as $p) {
            $t = explode(',', $p);
            if ($t[0] == $ci || $t[0] == '1' || $t[0] == '242') $valid[] = $c[$i];
        }
    }
    return $valid[rand(0, count($valid) - 1)];
}

$AD = get_ad();
$aid = $AD['id'] | 0;
if ($adtyp == 2) {
    $analyzer = new Analyzer($lid, $oid, $aid);
    $analyzer->_record('top_banner', 3);
}

$_user = new User($_GLOBAL['TABLES']['USERS'], $oid, System::getDB());
?>
```

Não funciona o total_clicks, views_left, spent_today, e o status.

Deu os seguintes erros:

> Warning: file_get_contents(/var/www/inc/VERSION.NS): failed to open
>   stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/inc/const.inc.php on
>   line 22
>
> Notice: Undefined index: UID in /var/www/global.php on line 30
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: G_UID in /var/www/fly/index.php on line 27
>
> Notice: Undefined index: HTTPS in /var/www/inc/utilities.class.php on
>   line 41

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow! Pode ser interessante ler os seguintes links: [tour], [help], [ask]

Comment: Comente a primeira linha do seu código `ini_set('display_errors', 0);`. Sem ela será possível ver quais erros sua página está retornando.

Comment: Vai vendo esses *warnings* e onde estão situados.

Comment: Não to conseguindo.

Comment: O programa não está encontrando o caminho `/var/www/inc/VERSION.NS` verifique se o arquivo realmente está nessa pasta.